# Infinix Hot 12i can't boot due to dm-verity corruption

Tags: boot, dm-verity, infinix

My Infinix Hot 12i on Android 11 is having this dm-verity corruption. The phone turned itself off and it can't boot.

I tried to flash, but it's saying `no command`. Nothing is working. The phone can't come on.

What do I do? And it's operating

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `fastboot flash vbmeta --disable-verity --disable-verification vbmeta.img` when flashing `vbmeta.img`?

OR;

Plug your phone in fastboot mode to PC and open command prompt in platform tools.

Type:

```
fastboot oem cdms
```